# WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions in Watch OS 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, watchos-3

I am developing Watch App for one of my iOS projects. But getting error of `NSExtensionPointIdentifier`. But as error suggested to set value `com.apple.watchkit`. But same value is there in WatchKit Extension Info.plist file.
There are other questions for the same issue, but they are not fit for watch os 3.0. and none of them working for me.

Xcode Version: Xcode 8.2
Watch OS: Watch OS 3.0

[image]

If anyone has idea then please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the images and make sure the bundle identifiers added in the same way and the version should be same for all target files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

....Hope this helps.